# Actionscript one way encryption

Tags: actionscript, encryption, hash, built-in

Is there a built in method in Actionscript 3 that allows you to create a hash of a string. Like MD5 and SHA1.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First link on google for "Actionscript3 md5"
http://gsolofp.blogspot.com/2006/01/actionscript-3-md5-and-sha1.html

As such, it looks like there is no built-in method.

Answer (score 0):

There is no builtin method for doing crypto things, but there exists some library that can be used:

- http://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/
- http://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/